# Hardcoding Subs with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

Is it possible to hardcode subs with ffmpeg? By hardcode, I mean overlaying the subtitles as pictures on top of the video, and would be unremovable because they would be a part of the video.
I tried to convert the subtitle to .ass and then tried to encode it, but ffmpeg does not do anything, and returns the same file. I used VLC to encode them, but it just embeds them in the video file itself and does not include them as pictured direclty overlayed on the video.
My end result should be something like this:

[image]

Created fonts.conf, then retried:

`Z:\New folder>ffmpeg -i input.wmv -vf "subtitle=sub.srt" output.wmv
ffmpeg version N-69247-g85d7e02 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 25 2015 02:18:48 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r
  libavutil      54. 17.100 / 54. 17.100
  libavcodec     56. 20.100 / 56. 20.100
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  8.101 /  5.  8.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from 'input.wmv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.101
    PRIVATE/TotalBitrate: 628000
    WM/VideoHeight  : 240
    WM/VideoWidth   : 320
    WM/VideoFrameRate: 0
    title           : input
  Duration: 01:47:53.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 656 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 320x240, SAR 120:67 DAR 160:67, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 128 kb/s
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002c5b4a0] No such filter: 'subtitle'
Error opening filters!`

I replaced `"subtitle=sub.srt"` with `subtitle="sub.srt"` and `subtitle=sub.srt` and got the same result.

I converted the subtitle to .ass: `ffmpeg -i sub.srt sub.ass`

Then I used `-vf ass=sub.ass` and the video encoded, but without subtitles.

I pasted exactly the same code given by in fonts.conf.

Also, how can I choose fonts? Should I use drawtext?

Comment: Please show the commands you've tried and the full command line output.

Comment: "but it just embeds them in the video file itself and does not include them as pictured direclty overlayed on the video". What do you mean?

Comment: @slhck the commands I used were: `ffmpeg -i subtitle.srt subtitle.ass` `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf ass=subtitle.ass output.mp4`

Comment: @rajib I mean that the subtitles are just embedded inside the video file, and can be turned on or off. I am looking for a way to include them in the video permanently.

Comment: Like I said, please show the command line output of these commands as well (the second one would be more interesting). You can [edit] your question to add the full log (starting with "ffmpeg version…" until the last line that you get when the encode is finished).

Comment: @slhck I did not include the command line output because it is nothing different. The process completes, but subtitles are not hardcoded. All I usually get is the input video as the output video.

Comment: The process doesn't complete.. Do you see the error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to hardcode subtitles, your ffmpeg version needs to be compiled with `libass` support. Download a static build from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html, and then use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -vf "subtitles=sub.srt" \
  -c:v libx264 -crf 20 \
  -c:a aac -b:a 192k
  output.mp4
```

Alternatively you can use `-vf "ass=sub.ass"` if you have ASS subtitles.

With this command, you set the source of the subtitles filter to the file containing the subtitles. If you want to burn the subtitles of the input video file itself, replace `sub.srt` with the name of the input video file.

You can change the CRF value to change the video quality/size. [More info on CRF here](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html).

More info on burning subtitles can be found [on the FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo).

Note that I replaced the WMV/WMA output from the original question with H.264 and AAC. ffmpeg doesn't have an encoder for recent versions of WMV, so your output would have looked quite bad. And since you're hardcoding the subtitles, you have to re-encode the video anyway.

In the OP's question, there was a typo:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002c5b4a0] No such filter: 'subtitle'
Error opening filters!
```

The filter is called `subtitles` with an `s`. Also, the ffmpeg version was not compiled with `--enable-libass`, so it could not be used to hardcode subs.

Comment: What would be the difference in the code if I used .ass subs? Is changing the font, and its size possible?

Comment: I suppose so. Not much of a subtitle expert, but using a proper subtitle editor would probably enable you to change the ASS subtitles to your liking.

Comment: YES! This worked! To change the subtitle size, color, etc just open the .ass file in a text editor and change the values manuallly. ffmpeg automatically uses the font default to the .ass file.

Comment: This was very useful to me today. I needed to add some overlay message on top of a screencapture video. Using a video editor and merging two video streams seemed daunting task. Then I thought of using subtitles and you showed a simple way of doing it. I already had an .mp4 and wanted an .mp4 output so that worked out very well as well

Comment: What about if the subs are already in the video file and i want to force them to be hardcoded?

Comment: @Grimeire In that case you have to use the video name as the source of the subtitles filter, e.g. `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf "subtitles=video.mkv" output.mkv`

Comment: Head's up, use `ass=sub.ass` rather than `subtitles=subs.ass`. It for some reason preserved some fonts correctly for me (maybe it's specific for the `ass` (**a**dvanced **s**ub**s**tation alpha) format. [Here's the page about it](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo).

Answer (score 9):

I have successfully tested this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.srt" output.mp4
```

**Note:** If the output says something about `No usable fontconfig configuration file found, using fallback`, you must create inside ffmpeg's bin folder a new folder named `fonts` with a file inside (`fonts.conf`) that specifies where ffmpeg must look for fonts.

I have used this file in order for it to work (tested on Windows):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<!-- /etc/fonts/fonts.conf file to configure system font access -->
<fontconfig>

<!-- Font directory list -->

   <dir>./</dir>
   <dir>../fonts</dir>
   <dir>./fonts</dir>
   <dir>~/.fonts</dir>
   <dir>WINDOWSFONTDIR</dir>

<!--
  Accept deprecated 'mono' alias, replacing it with 'monospace'
-->
   <match target="pattern">
      <test qual="any" name="family">
         <string>mono</string>
      </test>
      <edit name="family" mode="assign">
         <string>monospace</string>
      </edit>
   </match>

<!--
  Accept alternate 'sans serif' spelling, replacing it with 'sans-serif'
-->
   <match target="pattern">
      <test qual="any" name="family">
         <string>sans serif</string>
      </test>
      <edit name="family" mode="assign">
         <string>sans-serif</string>
      </edit>
   </match>

<!--
  Accept deprecated 'sans' alias, replacing it with 'sans-serif'
-->
   <match target="pattern">
      <test qual="any" name="family">
         <string>sans</string>
      </test>
      <edit name="family" mode="assign">
         <string>sans-serif</string>
      </edit>
   </match>

<!--
  Load local system customization file
-->
   <include ignore_missing="yes">conf.d</include>

<!-- Font cache directory list -->

   <cachedir>WINDOWSTEMPDIR_FONTCONFIG_CACHE</cachedir>
   <cachedir>~/.fontconfig</cachedir>

   <config>
<!--
  These are the default Unicode chars that are expected to be blank
  in fonts.  All other blank chars are assumed to be broken and
  won't appear in the resulting charsets
 -->
      <blank>
         <int>0x0020</int>   <!-- SPACE -->
         <int>0x00A0</int>   <!-- NO-BREAK SPACE -->
         <int>0x00AD</int>   <!-- SOFT HYPHEN -->
         <int>0x034F</int>   <!-- COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER -->
         <int>0x0600</int>   <!-- ARABIC NUMBER SIGN -->
         <int>0x0601</int>   <!-- ARABIC SIGN SANAH -->
         <int>0x0602</int>   <!-- ARABIC FOOTNOTE MARKER -->
         <int>0x0603</int>   <!-- ARABIC SIGN SAFHA -->
         <int>0x06DD</int>   <!-- ARABIC END OF AYAH -->
         <int>0x070F</int>   <!-- SYRIAC ABBREVIATION MARK -->
         <int>0x115F</int>   <!-- HANGUL CHOSEONG FILLER -->
         <int>0x1160</int>   <!-- HANGUL JUNGSEONG FILLER -->
         <int>0x1680</int>   <!-- OGHAM SPACE MARK -->
         <int>0x17B4</int>   <!-- KHMER VOWEL INHERENT AQ -->
         <int>0x17B5</int>   <!-- KHMER VOWEL INHERENT AA -->
         <int>0x180E</int>   <!-- MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR -->
         <int>0x2000</int>   <!-- EN QUAD -->
         <int>0x2001</int>   <!-- EM QUAD -->
         <int>0x2002</int>   <!-- EN SPACE -->
         <int>0x2003</int>   <!-- EM SPACE -->
         <int>0x2004</int>   <!-- THREE-PER-EM SPACE -->
         <int>0x2005</int>   <!-- FOUR-PER-EM SPACE -->
         <int>0x2006</int>   <!-- SIX-PER-EM SPACE -->
         <int>0x2007</int>   <!-- FIGURE SPACE -->
         <int>0x2008</int>   <!-- PUNCTUATION SPACE -->
         <int>0x2009</int>   <!-- THIN SPACE -->
         <int>0x200A</int>   <!-- HAIR SPACE -->
         <int>0x200B</int>   <!-- ZERO WIDTH SPACE -->
         <int>0x200C</int>   <!-- ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER -->
         <int>0x200D</int>   <!-- ZERO WIDTH JOINER -->
         <int>0x200E</int>   <!-- LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK -->
         <int>0x200F</int>   <!-- RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK -->
         <int>0x2028</int>   <!-- LINE SEPARATOR -->
         <int>0x2029</int>   <!-- PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR -->
         <int>0x202A</int>   <!-- LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING -->
         <int>0x202B</int>   <!-- RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING -->
         <int>0x202C</int>   <!-- POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING -->
         <int>0x202D</int>   <!-- LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE -->
         <int>0x202E</int>   <!-- RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE -->
         <int>0x202F</int>   <!-- NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE -->
         <int>0x205F</int>   <!-- MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE -->
         <int>0x2060</int>   <!-- WORD JOINER -->
         <int>0x2061</int>   <!-- FUNCTION APPLICATION -->
         <int>0x2062</int>   <!-- INVISIBLE TIMES -->
         <int>0x2063</int>   <!-- INVISIBLE SEPARATOR -->
         <int>0x206A</int>   <!-- INHIBIT SYMMETRIC SWAPPING -->
         <int>0x206B</int>   <!-- ACTIVATE SYMMETRIC SWAPPING -->
         <int>0x206C</int>   <!-- INHIBIT ARABIC FORM SHAPING -->
         <int>0x206D</int>   <!-- ACTIVATE ARABIC FORM SHAPING -->
         <int>0x206E</int>   <!-- NATIONAL DIGIT SHAPES -->
         <int>0x206F</int>   <!-- NOMINAL DIGIT SHAPES -->
         <int>0x2800</int>   <!-- BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK -->
         <int>0x3000</int>   <!-- IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE -->
         <int>0x3164</int>   <!-- HANGUL FILLER -->
         <int>0xFEFF</int>   <!-- ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE -->
         <int>0xFFA0</int>   <!-- HALFWIDTH HANGUL FILLER -->
         <int>0xFFF9</int>   <!-- INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION ANCHOR -->
         <int>0xFFFA</int>   <!-- INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION SEPARATOR -->
         <int>0xFFFB</int>   <!-- INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION TERMINATOR -->
      </blank>
<!--
  Rescan configuration every 30 seconds when FcFontSetList is called
 -->
      <rescan>
         <int>30</int>
      </rescan>
   </config>

</fontconfig>
```

Comment: How do I select a particular font? Is changing the color and size possible? Should I use this:`drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf`

Comment: @slhck pointed out that the command should be: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.srt" output.mp4`

Comment: Note the filter name being "subtitles", not "subtitle"

Comment: I didn't get the font error, the command worked nicely, just note that you have to be in the folder that the srt file is located in, `"subtitles=C:\Users\user\Videos\sub.srt"` won't work.

Comment: For someone who uses along with `-ss <time> -to <time>` to extract a part of video then makes sure the subtitle time should follow the time of the output (which starts from 00:00) not the original video.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v subtitles=subtitle.srt -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

This way it works with regular FFmpeg on Linux, without any special libraries compiled into it.

More information and parameters to change:

https://copyprogramming.com/howto/ffmpeg-hardcoded-subtitles-from-the-top-bigger-with-thicker-stroke-on-a-dark-background